# Zend Framework – Modules, Forms, ViewScripts and ViewHelpers

Tags: zend-framework, forms, module

I have a search module. It has one form within it that produces the search field, I am using a viewScript that is stored within views/scripts/forms to render the form.

I want this form to appear on ever screen so I have written a ViewHelper that creates the from and returns it. This works fine when I am within the search module but when I am in any other module I am getting an error.

Any ideas why?

This is what is used to create the viewScript in the form

```
$this->setDecorators(array(
    array( 'ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'forms/Search.phtml'))
));
```

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

In my code I have to put a / in front of the path so for you it would mean:

```
$this->setDecorators(array(
    array( 'ViewScript', array('viewScript' => '/forms/Search.phtml'))
));
```

Comment: Hi Iznogood, thanks for the response, still getting the same error I'm afraid.

Comment: Just noticed you say search module. Is it a real module or do you just call views modules.

Comment: So you are trying to call a viewscript from another module? Is it possible you need to ajust the path of the viewscript when you try ton invokle it from another module?